# Makeshift carboy

Tags: carboy

Can I use a large jug, such as a Carlo Rosse bottle, with an added airlock as a carboy for fermentation? Are there any issues with this or things I should make sure to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. At the end of the day, a carboy is just a container. They're not rated for pressure, they're not thermally-hardened, they're … just a container. Glass is glass is glass.  (Plastics come in various types; oxygen permeability and surface roughness are particular concerns). You might have "trouble" finding the right size airlock for the opening, but airlocks are overrated anyways. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for my doubts to bed. I figured that was probably the case, but wanted to make sure as I have never done this and did not want to pour money down the drain with a ruined batch.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't do that, assuming thorough cleaning and sanitation.